# Save page source in Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, json, variables

I am studying javascript and I've got some problems. I would like to save the source of a page (html, json, xml) in a javascript variable. I didn't find much surfing on the net so could you help me? Actually the page is on an external domain so how can I get around the same origin policy limitation?

Comment: I suspect what ever it is you're trying to achieve, you're going about it in the wrong way. What is the goal of "saving the source"?

Comment: You cannot "get around" the Same Origin Policy.  If you could, the Internet would be a disaster.

Comment: I'm trying to save the content of a json file (I'd like to copy to save all the lines of the json file in a javascript array)

Comment: I think you can use YQL. But I'm not sure how will you mitigate the same origin policy or put in other words, how YQL takes care of the same. Personally, I've never used YQL but I know that it can fetch the HTML...   `select * from HTML where url="http://cnn.com"` fetches the source of HTML.. http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

Comment: @Bulk: How apt is it to use YQL for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe you can pull the entire source code from an external domain without a server-side script such as PHP.  The only cross-domain compatible format is JSONP, which with JQuery would require a JSON response from the other server.  Both may pose a security risk to your webpage.

#### UPDATE:

[See here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) for more information.